# Fetching user data from JSON to an expanded select box and displaying the value when option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to get the json data from a file which has a nested JSON objects, like this.

```
{
    "userId": "1",
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name" : "Lorem Ipsum",
        "value" : "Salut Dolor"
    } 
}
```

And once I get it I want to create a select object with the Id as the displayed text and append it to a div.
Once the select object is created, I also want to automatically open the select options when the page gets loaded.
Once a value is selected from there, I want to display the name that is present in the json for that id.

I'm able to fetch only the UserId from this code, how will i meet the requirements?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'obj.json',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            items.push('<option id="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
        });
        $('<select/>', {
            class: 'intrest-list',
            html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('body');
    },
    statusCode: {
        404: function () {
            alert("There was a problem");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. Although i came up with an alternative to display the list of select elements as:

```
<select name="" id="details" size="2"></select>
```

also created a container to post the values of the JSON object selected from the select box:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

and the jQuery part where the magic happens goes like this:

```
$.getJSON('obj.json', function(obj) {
        $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
             $("#details").append('<option>'+ value.name +'</option>')
        });

        $( "select" ).change(function () {
            var value = $( "select option:selected").val();

            $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
                if (val.name == value) {
                    $("#container").html(val.value);
                } 
            });
        });
});
```

This pretty much made the select box as a list of items and the value.name selected in it makes the value.value visible in the div container.

Answer (score 1):

what is this good for? do you want to fetch more then 1 user in the future?
you could so something like this:

```
//user.json
[{id:1,name:'xxxx'},...]

....
 for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
  items.push('<option id="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name+'</option>');
 }
...
```

or in your case, you can access it directly with:

```
data.data.id
data.data.name
data.data.value
```

would get you the right values

Comment: How would u fetch the value when u select the data element from the select box? I guess a .click() function would be needed. And also, how would you open the select box when the page loads?

Comment: you once declar this something like this, after you added the select to the dom: $( "select" ).change(function () {$( "select option:selected").html();});

Comment: Thanx for the help @yellowsir. You were helpful.